# Shell Script via Crontab - Start Jetty, works fine manually, but not via crontab

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
jettyPid=`pgrep -f solr`

if [ "$jettyPid" == "" ]
then
   /etc/init.d/jetty start &
fi
```

It works fine if a execute:

```
./script.sh.
```

The problem is that if I put this on a cron job, the Jetty won’t start, however, it log to my log file:

> Starting Jetty: STARTED Jetty Fri Jun…

I do not understand why it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the PATH in your cronjob file

In my case,

```
echo $PATH 
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Add the Path in your crontab : `crontab -e`

```
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

30 5 * * * runmyscript
```

You can check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What does your crontab entry for this look like?

Also, the issue with this script might be that you are not specifying `bash` as the interpreter:

```
jettyPid=`pgrep -f solr`

if [ "$jettyPid" == "" ]
then
   /etc/init.d/jetty start &
fi
```

Try adding `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in the file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
jettyPid=`pgrep -f solr`

if [ "$jettyPid" == "" ]; then
   /etc/init.d/jetty start &
fi
```

If you do not specify `bash` the cron job will just use the standard system shell. Also note that I added `;` and moved the `then` up to the `if` line. This kind of syntax is more standard to the way `bash` scripts are handled.

Past any of that if the Jetty setup requires any libraries that are part of your own personal `$PATH` but not a part of the systemwide `$PATH` it will fail.  The answer `chamzzey` provides is correct, but if any of the paths change, this will break again. It might be best for the long term to look into the Jetty code & set explicit paths to libraries or required tools if possible.

Comment: Jake, I have  bash on my script. Include PATH as chamzzey said works fine. Thanks